# what's the best way to get all Teams owners and members

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, microsoft-teams, office-365-groups

Is there a way from admin center to export all teams owners and members to a CSV file?

I can't run the following code b/c I think it depends on graph api and it might be blocked.

```
# PowerShell script to export all Microsoft Teams Owners and Members to a CSV file
$Result = ""
$Results = @()
$Path = "./All Teams Members and Owner Report_$((Get-Date -format yyyy-MMM-dd-ddd` hh-mm` tt).ToString()).csv"

Write-Host "Exporting all Teams members and owners report..."

$Count = 0
Get-Team | foreach {
    $TeamName = $_.DisplayName
    Write-Progress -Activity "`nProcessed Teams count: $Count" "`nCurrently Processing: $TeamName"
    $Count++
    $GroupId = $_.GroupId
    Get-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupId | foreach {
        $Name = $_.Name
        $MemberMail = $_.User
        $Role = $_.Role
        $Result = @{
            'Teams Name' = $TeamName;
            'Member Name' = $Name;
            'Member Mail' = $MemberMail;
            'Role' = $Role
        }
        $Results = New-Object psobject -Property $Result
        $Results | select 'Teams Name', 'Member Name', 'Member Mail', 'Role' | Export-Csv $Path -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}

Write-Progress -Activity "`nProcessed Teams count: $Count" "`nCurrently Processing: $TeamName" -Completed

if ((Test-Path -Path $Path) -eq "True") {
    Write-Host "`nReport available in $Path" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: `Get-Team` is part of the Microsoft Teams PowerShell module. Did you try to install it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-powershell-install

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Microsoft Teams PowerShell module to run the PowerShell script you provided in your post.

**Documentation**: [Microsoft Teams PowerShell Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/teams-powershell-overview?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

You can also use PnP PowerShell or CLI for Microsoft 365 for exporting owners and members or Microsoft teams.

**PnP PowerShell**:

```
$AdminCenterURL="https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/"

# Connect to SharePoint Online admin center

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminCenterURL -Interactive

$dateTime = (Get-Date).toString("dd-MM-yyyy")
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
$fileName = "m365GroupUsersReport-" + $dateTime + ".csv"
$OutPutView = $directorypath + "\Logs\"+ $fileName

# Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$m365GroupCollection = @()

# Retrieve all M365 groups associated with Microsoft teams
$m365Groups = Get-PnPMicrosoft365Group | where-object {$_.HasTeam -eq $true}

$m365Groups | ForEach-Object {
    $ExportVw = New-Object PSObject
    $ExportVw | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Group Name" -value $_.DisplayName
    $m365GroupOwnersName="";
    $m365GroupMembersName="";
    
    # For auditing purpose
    $m365GroupOwnersName = (Get-PnPMicrosoft365GroupOwner -Identity $_.GroupId | select -ExpandProperty DisplayName) -join ";";
    $m365GroupMembersName = (Get-PnPMicrosoft365GroupMember -Identity $_.GroupId | select -ExpandProperty DisplayName) -join ";";

    $ExportVw | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Group Owners" -value $m365GroupOwnersName
    $ExportVw | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Group Members" -value $m365GroupMembersName
    $m365GroupCollection += $ExportVw
}

# Export the result array to CSV file
$m365GroupCollection | sort "Group Name" |Export-CSV $OutPutView -Force -NoTypeInformation

# Disconnect SharePoint online connection

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

**CLI for Microsoft 365**:

```
$dateTime = (Get-Date).toString("dd-MM-yyyy")
$directorypath = "D:\dtemp"
$fileName = "MSTeamsUsersReport-" + $dateTime + ".csv"
$OutPutView = $directorypath + "\"+ $fileName

# Array to hold results - PSObjects
$msTeamsUsersCollection = @()

# Get Credentials to connect
$m365Status = m365 status
if ($m365Status -match "Logged Out") {
    m365 login
}

# Retrieve all teams in Microsoft Teams
$msTeams = m365 teams team list | ConvertFrom-Json

$msTeams | ForEach-Object {
    $ExportVw = New-Object PSObject
    $ExportVw | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Team Name" -value $_.displayName
    $teamOwnerNames = "";
    $teamMemberNames = "";
    $teamGuestNames = "";
    
    $teamOwnerNames = (m365 teams user list --teamId $_.id --role Owner | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty displayName) -join ";"
    $teamMemberNames = (m365 teams user list --teamId $_.id --role Member | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty displayName) -join ";"
    $teamGuestNames = (m365 teams user list --teamId $_.id --role Guest | ConvertFrom-Json | select -ExpandProperty displayName) -join ";"
    
    $ExportVw | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Team Owners" -value $teamOwnerNames
    $ExportVw | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Team Members" -value $teamMemberNames
    $ExportVw | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Team Guests" -value $teamGuestNames
    $msTeamsUsersCollection += $ExportVw
}

# Export the results to CSV file
$msTeamsUsersCollection | sort "Team Name" |Export-CSV $OutPutView -Force -NoTypeInformation

# Disconnect M365 connection
m365 logout
```

**Source**: [List all Microsoft Teams team's Owners and Members](https://pnp.github.io/script-samples/teams-list-teams-owners-and-members/README.html?tabs=pnpps)

Comment: why am I getting localhost :0501 error after i put in admin credentials. and I didn't get authencator code

Comment: Which PowerShell code are you exactly now, MS Teams PS or PnP PowerShell or CLI for M365? You mean you have MFA enabled for your account?